# Symfony security redirect to login page

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

If I have a secured route, let's say like `panel` from below, Symfony will allow access only to logged in users.

```
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/panel, role: ROLE_USER }
```

For users that are not logged in it will always redirect them to the login_path (I'm using FOSUserBundle):

```
security:
    firewalls:   
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path:     fos_user_security_login
```

Where can I disable or override this redirect? I want to show a login form directly, without redirecting the user.

I believe it has to do with `AccessDeniedHandlerInterface`, but what key needs to be overwritten in security.yml? And where is the default implementation?

For other situations we have `DefaultLogoutSuccessHandler, DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler, DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and we can implement a service for each of these situations, that extends their respective interfaces and can handle the situation in a custom manner. Can't find anything for AccessDenied, though. [Its directory](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authorization) contains only the interface.

Comment: What's the benefit? After logging in the user would get redirected back to /panel and it wouldn't feel any different - what am I missing?

Comment: I want to add a login page on a few routes. User wants to access the page but he's not logged in so I present him the login form and after login (with ajax) he gets redirected to panel.

Comment: to show a login form you should allow anonymous access too. So check for permission in a controller for example

Comment: Makes sense. Still, I'd like to know where this check is being made. For other cases we have  `AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface,AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface,  LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface`. I believe it's the interface `AccessDeniedHandlerInterface`
 but where do I need to include the service that implements this and where is the default?

Comment: Regarding your first comment: The end-user result is exactly the same as the default implementation (user is logged in -> sees page directly, user is not logged in -> redirect to login page -> login sucecssful -> redirect to panel) except it's working with HTTP redirects instead of AJAX. That's what I'm asking: Is there a technical necessity to change this behaviour to AJAX?

Comment: Yes, I've already changed the login with ajax only and made the login page ajax-accessible only. This means the security component tries to redirect to a page that accepts only ajax and an exception is thrown.

Comment: In that case: Manually rendering a different page might be your best bet. I would suggest a kernel controller listener to check if the user is logged in and if your controlelr implements a certain (can be empty) interface and do the work there. This way you can re-use it in different controllers.

Comment: That could work, but I still want to know how the AccessDeniedHandlerInterface works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this manually.

Make your route accessible by anonymous:

```
- { path: ^/panel, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER] }
```

In your template, check if there is a logged in user:

```
{% if app.user is null %}
    <!-- Then display your login form -->
{% else %}
    <!-- Display the normal view -->
{% endif %}
```

Or do it from the controller:

```
if (!is_object($this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser())) {
    // Render the login form
}
```

Like this, you can make your logic depending on that the user is authenticated or not.

Comment: Considering that the user wants to access the panel page and he gets redirected to a page where I display the login form (taken and validated with ajax), how do I know what page to redirect the user after login(in this case page) and how do I know if the user wanted initially to login or not(the login form is a modal and the content is retrieved with ajax)?

Comment: In your question you are saying that you don't want to redirect the user, only display the login form. To know which page your user tries to access,  use `app.request.headers.get('referer')` from twig or `$this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer')` from controller. Then, if you want redirect to the referer after login, add  a `_target_path` as form field, fill it with the retrieved referer and make the redirection in the method that handles your form (if your form is handled by FOSUser, the `_target_path` will be automatically used). I can make a quick edit if you need an example.